# UIView slide animation using blocks instead?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, slide, block

How can I get the following animation to work in blocks?

(I need the keyboard to dissappear in the completion handler of the transition animation)

```
- (void) showNewViewAnimatedSlideAscending:(BOOL)isAscending {
    UIView * oldView = self.myView;
    UIView * newView = self.myView;
    UIView * superView = self.myView.superview;

    [oldView removeFromSuperview];
    [superView addSubview:newView];

    // set up an animation for the transition between the views
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.3];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    if(isAscending) {
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    } else {
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    }
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [[superView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"myTransitionAnimation"];
    if(self.keyboardVisible) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }
}
```

p.s; I know, I'm removing and showing the same view. This view has received new data just before calling this method. Somehow the view displays correctly and only shows the new data in the 'new' view.

Comment: Read the documentation. Look for a method called `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` on UIView

Comment: Unfortunately, under options, UIViewAnimationOptionTransition doesn't allow for a 'sliding' transition. This is why I can't figure out how to create the above animation in blocks.